# how can i debugg an android service - activity that extends service class -

Tags: android, eclipse, android-service

colleagues,

how can i debug an activity that extends the service class?
Its not working with the regualar breakpoints of the eclipse debugging tool!
I know that you can work with logtags but is this really the only debugging tool??

heres a little code sniped to be able to post this question

```
                   public class HUJIDataCollectionService extends Service {
           @Override
public void onStart(Intent intent, int startId) {
    super.onStart(intent, startId);

         }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Is your service declared in the manifest to run in a seperate process to your main application process? For example:

```
<service android:name=".HUJIDataCollectionService"
      android:process=":SomeOtherProcess">
</service>
```

If so, you will need create a special case debug configuration in Eclipse to get the debugger to attach to that process. Check out this article for step by step instructions:

http://blog.doityourselfandroid.com/2010/12/07/debug-remote-android-proces-eclipse/